# Eloquent - Many to many where not found in the pivot table

Tags: php, eloquent

My DB is set up like...

Accounts --< Accounts_Games >-- Games

```
Accounts
---------
id            INT

Accounts_Games
---------
id            INT
account_id    INT
game_id       INT

Games
---------
id            INT
```

I have managed to get a list of Games by a single Account quite easily using belongsToMany. Now I need to get a list of Games that an Account is NOT joined to.

How can I achieve this in Eloquent?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am didn't know your tables fields in your each tables.

but you can do with this way : add 1 method like this in GamesEloquent file :

```
public function account_not_join()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Account', 'accounts_games', 'game_id', 'account_id')->where('is_join', 0);
}
```

Comment: I get an exception... Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'is_join' in 'where clause'

Comment: as I said before, I am didn't know your field in your each tables.

in my example that explain if in your accounts_games table have field (is_join)

Comment: I've updated the original question with a quick overview of the tables used